# Can't use IBActon for button on after installing iPhone SDK 3.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.2

I have no idea what happened after installing this update ... I can't do this most simple thing which I've been using for a long time. Does anyone have the same problem as I do?

Comment: Could you give more detail on what steps you have taken and how it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes updating an SDK results in "weird things" happening.  Try deleting or renaming the `/Developer` folder, and then re-installing the SDK.

If that doesn't fix it, try deleting `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Xcode.plist`.

Comment: the problem was just caused by BETA iPhone SDK :)